# Designing a mazebot with A*/Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, robotics, a-star, maze

**Problem:**

I do not understand how to fully implement A* or Dijkstra's algorithm in a maze following robot. The robot is in a dynamically generated maze, and can only see ahead of itself (how far away an object in front of it is), and can move forward and backwards, and can rotate ("tank drive"). While only seeing forward, I cannot figure out how to accuratly judge the risk/value of the surrounding possibilities of movement.

Aditionally, I imagine storage might be a problem for memory of the board, but I will make another question for that after this one is answered.

**Backstory:**

I am mentoring a group of kids that is participating in FTC, and they are using block programming for their robot. I am challenging myself to understand and fully work with block programming in order to be able to help them to the fullest of my capability.

Thanks to anyone who can help, and have a great day;
-Kai

Comment: If the robot position is known and the target position is known you can use A*. All you need is to define how to get the next possible moves (neighbors) at each location and their costs. It is not clear to me what are the possible moves. Please [edit] your question to clarify. You can start by allying dijkstra's algorism and enhance it to A* later

Comment: @c0der, I have changed the main body of my question to be more percise, although it isn't very good, generally

Comment: Assuming an rectangular maze of size `n * m` you could for instance model each coordinate `x/y` as a node in a graph. And create an edge between two adjacent nodes `n1 = x1/y1` and `n2 = x2/y2` if you can take a step from `n1` to `n2`. Then you can apply Dijkstra to find the shortest path from the entry to the exit of the maze.

Comment: If you want the robot to act like "can only see ahead of itself," maybe this isn't the best algorithm to use? Or perhaps you assume that it's clear, and when you get more information (wall positions), you update the stored model?

Comment: @Neil, is there a better maze solving program you could suggest for a robot that only has access to the distance of the object in front of it? This is the only one that I have found that I know of, and one of my past mentors has made a MicroMouse robot that was able to us A* to navigate while only visibly seeing ahead of it.

Comment: If the robot can move backward and forward and also rotate 360 degrees the relevant "neighbors" or next cells are all the cells **around** it. So you may need to rotate the robot, scan its immediate surrounding, and map all next cells. Unless the game plan has other restrictions the cost of the move to the next step is the distance to it.

Comment: Some version of DFS seems to be popular, [Cai et al, 2012, FloodFill Maze](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6332345), [Tjiharjadi et al, 2017, Optimization Maze](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Semuil-Tjiharjadi/publication/319943074_Optimization_Maze_Robot_Using_A_and_Flood_Fill_Algorithm/links/5e91e2b9a6fdcca7890ac885/Optimization-Maze-Robot-Using-A-and-Flood-Fill-Algorithm.pdf), [Mahmud et al, 2012, Greedy Approach](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6509798). I imagine that would be less optimal if the walls are sparse.